# Hide labels in pie chart

Tags: .net-4.0, charts

Am I going mad/blind? Probably a combination of the two.

How does one go about removing the data labels from a pie chart with the new chart control in .net 4?

I can get these to display as tooltips absolutely fine, but ultiamtely I'd like the labels not to be present as it looks rather busy.

I've searched previous answers and seen code behind resolutions but surely there must be some sort of code infront option to turn these labels off?

Apologies for being thick/blind.

Answer (score 3):

```
EstadoPie2.Series("EstadoSummarySeries")("PieLabelStyle") = "Disabled"
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

for (var i = 0; i < Chart.Series.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart.Series[i]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
            }